# Compile time error while integrating Level Helper code in Cocos2d project

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

[image]I am trying to add Levels into my cocos2d game using sprite builder and level helper. After I add all the files into the project that are generated by level helper, my project starts giving me error. I have attached an image which shows the error that I am getting. Any help will be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: The problem raised which I tried to add the Level Helper code in Cocos2d 2.0 Box2d arc template. If a create a new project using box2d template from Xcode(non arc), level helper codes compile successfully.  How can I resolve these issues in arc based project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested LevelHelper code against ARC (again) and all is compiling just fine. Please, when you have LevelHelper related problems write on GameDevHelper.com forum so that i can answer you asap. 
Your problems seam to be related with a missing inclusion as Steffen mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

No interface for NSObject could mean there's a `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` missing.

Comment: I see that the #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> is mentioned in pch file. I also imported the foundation framework to LHCustomSpriteMgr which cannot find interface declaration of NSObject. While compiling, I get lot of new errors. Please open the link (http://i.imgur.com/hJgbiet.png) to find the screen shot of xcode. Project.